# How to return empty json array in asp.net core

Tags: json, asp.net-core, serialization, asp.net-core-webapi, json-serialization

In ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API, when an `object` is empty, it will return a JSON array with `null` values like this:

```
{
    "code": "1",
    "message": null,
    "data": {
        "formSettings": [
            null,
            null
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I return a response as shown in the below code, such that the JSON array has empty objects:

```
{
    "code": "1",
    "message": null,
    "data": {
        "formSettings": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly share your Model/DTO which generates this JSON result

Answer (score 0):

This is best way to send the empty json.

{
    "code": "1",
    "message": null,
    "data": {
        "formSettings": []
            }
}

Comment: I know, But how I can return response like below code. When I return response by standart way response look like my first example

Answer (score 0):

I could return `empty json` when add below code to `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddMvc()
             .AddJsonOptions(options => {
                 options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
             });
```